# Java EE Authority constraint for everyone

Tags: security, jakarta-ee

I'm new to Java EE and I'm trying to figure out how to provide access to a specific resource for everyone. I've tried the following example because it looked simple but it still brings me to the logon form that I have specified elsewhere in the `web.xml`.

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Everywhere</web-resource-name>
        <description>Allow every one to access everything</description>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

When I swap out the url pattern for `/bogus`, which isn't a match, the logon form doesn't load. Any ideas?

Comment: So are you saying everything is not accessible except for some resource ?

Comment: It's not allowing access to all resources. My assumption is that placing that `*` for the role-name (and having no other security-constraint) would have allowed any user to access anything in the site but it doesn't appear to be doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "*" role, with the semantics of meaning "any user in any role" (even a user without roles) was only added in Java EE 7.

Since Java EE 7 is not officially released yet, chances are high you're running Java EE 6 or below.

GlassFish 4 (which implements Java EE 7) will be released very soon though (estimation: couple of weeks at most, perhaps sooner). If you're just learning for yourself, you could opt to start with GlassFish 4 right away and there the "*" role should indeed work.

Comment: Is there a way to do say "for these resources, you need to be authenticated" ?

Comment: @sgcharlie yes, define a security constraint in web.xml for these resources and then constrain them to this "*" role.